# Altering DEFAULT Value of Date

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Table which has a date field which looks like this:

```
 | date          | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
```

I am using this query to change it's default value :

```
 alter table builds alter column date SET DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

But It does not seem to change the default value for the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to a `datetime` type instead of a `timestamp`

```
ALTER TABLE builds MODIFY `date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```